# Selecionar um arquivo via javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

Tenho uma pasta com varios arquivos pdf e precisava selecionar o pdf 1348.pdf, mas via javascript, é possivel fazer isso ? Teria que utilizar um handler ? e como eu devolveria esse valor (binary,nome e tamanho) ?

~/arquivos/1348.pdf

Em um método do server ficaria assim:

```
 DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/arquivos/"));
                FileInfo[] arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles("1348.pdf");
```

Queria saber como faço isso via javascript

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer, com exemplos de preferencia

Comment: @RafaelAugusto coloquei um código de exemplo que seria no servidor precisava para o javascript mas não sei se é possivel.

Comment: O que você pretende fazer com a seleção desse arquivo?

Comment: Se os arquivos estão no servidor você precisa de algum script server-side (.net, php e etc) ou até dá para fazer "só" com javascript... mas você precisa poder configurar o servidor para que ele permita o acesso browse de conteúdo diretamente ao diretório.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto eu fiz uma tela que carrega os dados via javascript sem ir ao banco e eu incluo um arquivo pdf por dado caso o usuário deseje, mas quando eu carregar a pagina em outro dia e tiver os dados la eu preciso carregar esse pdf, para que ele saiba que tem um arquivo la e/ou caso deseje exclui-lo, então basicamente para mostrar o nome ao usuário e armazenar no fileupload e depois excluir se o cliente desejar.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo ok então basicamente vou precisar utilizar um metódo ajax que envie os parametros como "nome do arquivo" e no handler eu seleciono o arquivo, mas ai como eu voltaria esse arquivo pro ajax? context.Response.Write(arquivo) ?

Comment: Desculpa, @Voltz, mas ainda está um pouco confuso o que você pretende fazer. Você quer exibir o pdf em uma página web, baixar o arquivo ou exibir na tela a lista de arquivos que você possui nesse diretório?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Se eu conseguir listar todos via javascript acho que eu já consigo seguir com meu problema

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu só preciso pegar os arquivos pra depois poder deleta-los, tudo isso via javascript/webmethod/handler